# remove apostrophes and other marks files from apostrophes

Tags: text-processing

How to remove apostrophes and other marks such as (Parkinson’s and Parkinson's  ) from all text files in a directory and save the changes in each one of the  files as in the directory

Comment: What are the "other marks"?

Comment: Please give example input files and your desired output. What does "save the changes in each one of the files _as in_ the directory" mean? Do you want copies of each file or do you want to modify the original files in place?

Comment: I need to save the changes in the original files

Comment: @kyle Your sentence is ambiguous. If you want to overwrite the original files, a better preposition to use is "into": into the original files. Or just say that you want to edit the files "in place".

Answer (score 3):

Pick up one of the following snippets :

```
$ sed -i -r "s/[’']/ /g" file.txt
$ cat file.txt
Parkinson s and Parkinson s
```

or

```
$ perl -i -pe 's/(\342\200\231|\047)/ /g' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
Parkinson s and Parkinson s
```

or

```
$ perl -i -lpe 's/\W+/ /g' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
Parkinson s and Parkinson s
```